# Enable SSH only when connected to VPN (OpenVPN)

Tags: openvpn

I have OpenVPN installed on Ubuntu 12.04 and want only client logged in through the VPN to access SSH on the same server. I have NAT enabled. Is there a way to accept SSH connections that way.

Thanks.

Comment: Abhishek, although this is a *valid* question for serverfault, the person who referred you here probably didn't realize that this is a site for *professional system administrators*, you will find help here, but it's best to ask these types of questions on the Ubuntu or Unix/Linux StackExchange sites.

Answer (score 2):

A few ways to resolve this:

- configure the SSH-daemon to only listen on the IP used for VPN clients (and possibly other internal ranges) using the `ListenAddress` statement.
- configure a firewall to only allow the VPN IP-range for SSH